# The 'x' parameter is missing a value in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, parameters

Although many times posted on the Internet it didn't give me the answer yet.
I have an Internal parameter with a default value as "Get values from a query". The Report runs fine as long as there is output from the query. Otherwise the above error pops up. I have tried all possible solution posted. Nothing helps.
If I define the parameter as Visible it works fine as well.
Does anyone has a suggestion not posted yet?

Comment: Is this a multivalue parameter? Also provide more info like parameter type

Comment: No and allow Blank and Null values are on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it so your query always returns something. Without a value for your parameter, the report will not run (thus your error). You can return a value that you know means there were no results and have your report perform any logic desired based on that value.

Comment: Tx very Much, I added a union in the query with some fictitious values.

Comment: @MichelvanEijk Glad it worked out, can you please mark this as the answer?